# highcharts - is it possible to zoom pie charts

Tags: charts, highcharts, zooming, slice, pie-chart

I'm wondering if it is possible to zoom in on a slice in a pie chart.

My chart is modeled after this example [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-donut/)

```
chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'area',
            zoomType: 'x',
        }
```

But it doesn't seem to work with pie charts. Am I missing something here?
Ideally, I would have a pie chart with 2 layers, where the outer layer serves as a child of the inner layer. When selecting a child slice, I could then have an entire pie chart showing that slice alone, along with its own children, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunaltely zoom is not allowed for Pie Charts as its properties show you

x: to zoom in x-axis
y: to zoom in y-axis
xy: to zoom in both axes

but you can use `size` property with JavaScript to show zooming.
[size property demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/74T6h/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I was actually looking for. It isn't zoom, but rather the option of capturing click events on slices.

In order to do that, one must use the `allowPointSelect` attribute, which can be added to a pie chart like this (just one of several different ways):

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        shadow: false,
        allowPointSelect: true,
    },
}
```

Then in order to capture clicks one has to declare the `events` attribute in the `series` being used:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Example',
    data: [
        {
            name: 'Firefox',   
            value: 45.0
        },
        {
            name: 'IE',
            value: 26.8
        },
        {
            name: 'Chrome',
            value: 12.8,
        },
    ],
    size: '100%',
    point: {
        events: {
           click: function() {
               // some code to execute when clicking a slice
               alert('Slice name: ' + this.name + ' and value: ' + this.value);
           }
        }
    }
}]
```

Then in that click function, any javascript code can be executed, and the declared fields in the data can also be accessed. So a second pie chart could theoretically be created on the fly.